# Selectively build boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way to install specific libraries along with it's dependent libraries?

For example, I want to use only Asio in Boost and I want to install only Asio and required libraries on which Asio is dependent(it seems that boost/system is).

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a version of ASIO which does not require any boost libraries: https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio

Comment: Thanks @m.s. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool that's part of the distribution to copy specific libraries, dependencies, and do a few other tasks for dealing with subparts of Boost.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to copy the desired libraries (and not copy any others) into a directory you wish to use, then link to this limited subset of the full boost library.

For example, I have an application in which I prefer to use the archive libs.  To avoid the .so's (which the linker would choose if available), my build has a simple rule to trigger

```
 cp  /usr/local/lib/libboost*.a  ../
```

At link time, I specify my dir in a -L.

Comment: Thanks @DOUGLAS. But seems like your way requires building whole boost library.

Comment: @JaeJunLEE - possibly ... but the build instructions do all of it, and it would be much more work to pick a subset.  Perhaps you can download a pre-built binary.  BEFORE you try, please note that I can find no specific library (.a or .so) with asio in the name ... so possibly you only need the hpp files?  I do have plenty of hpp files which appear to be asio specific.